# Create a row each third post

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm working on the search results output for Wordpress website and would like to split a row each third post. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <div class="post-wrapper">

                <?php
                while ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();
                    ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div>


        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Now it gets all results but just in one column and I'd like to have three columns. Theme is using Bootstrap so all I need is to add a 'row' each third post but I just can't figure out how to implement this into the PHP template as above. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for inspiration. Outputs:

```
0
1
2
-- BREAK --
3
4
5
-- BREAK --
6
7
8
-- BREAK --
9
```

Code:

```
<?php

// Loop 10 times.
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    // If $i MOD 3 evaluates to zero, then we've reached the end of a group of three items.
    // Skip when $i is zero, unless you want to show a break before any output.
    if ($i && !($i % 3))
        // Output a row separator
        echo "-- BREAK --\n";
        
    // Output a row with some column values.
    echo "$i\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Group every 3 posts in one row. Checking the total number of posts avoids a new div in the last element.

```
$loop_posts = new WP_Query(
    array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'no_found_rows' => true, 
    )
);
$count = 1;
$found_posts= $loop_posts->post_count;
if ($loop_posts->have_posts()) :
    echo '<div class="row">';
    while ( $loop_posts->have_posts() ) : $loop_posts->the_post();  ?>
        <?php       
            get_template_part( 'includes/news_element', get_post_format() ); 
            if($count % 3==0 && $count <= $found_posts){
                echo '</div><div class="row">';
            }
            $count++;
        ?>
        <?php 
    endwhile;
    echo '</div>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```